# uploadprogress_get_info and large files

Tags: php, ajax, upload, pecl

It seems that the PECL package "uploadprogress" works on files less then 10MB,

But Anything greater than 10MB, it fails miserably.

I've changed my php.ini to support larger upload, but it just doesn't return anything!

Any Help on this?

Comment: How exactly did you change your php.ini to allow files larger than 10MB?

Comment: Edited the php.ini in the directory:
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 40M

Answer (score 1):

After changing upload_max_filesize and post_max_size to some larger value in php.ini.  Then don't forget to restart apache.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note with uploadProgress.

Providing you have installed UploadProgress correctly, if you are still having issues and you have installed Modsecurity, read on.

If you are using modsecurity you will need to edit 
/etc/httpd/conf.d/modsecurity.conf using your favourite editor

Eg.

```
vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/modsecurity.conf
```

Modsecurity will stop uploadprogress working due to buffering issues.. in short you can fix this but at some security cost to your server:

First (and by doing so opening a security risk) edit the line:

```
SecRequestBodyAccess On
```

change the directive to

```
SecRequestBodyAccess Off
```

(after an apache/ server restart your upload progress should work!)

Don't forget if you have installed ModSecurity you will also need to edit a directive for large file uploads, as modsecurity takes charge of the max upload file size, to do so edit this directive:

```
SecRequestBodyLimit 3107200
```

as an example you will need to up the number in bits to allow the maximum bytes you intend to allow your users to upload.

10M would look like this:

```
SecRequestBodyLimit 10485760
```

Don't forget to restart your server

(for cent users you can do service httpd restart)

Both of these issues threw me for days!
Hope it helps..